# Temperature spikes on Ryzen 2600 - sensor fail?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, hardware-failure, temperature, amd-ryzen

Sometimes my PC turns off because of high CPU temperature (around 100°C in idle or browsing web etc). But I'm 100% sure this temperature was not real. When I looked at HWMonitor (on Windows) and Psensor (on Linux) there were a lot of spikes of CPU temperature. The spikes are usually around 10-15°C. For example, it's 45°C for 2-3 minutes and value *instantly* changes to 55-60°C. After that it's decreasing bit by bit for 20-30 seconds to 45°C and the loop starts again. Sometimes the temperature goes to 70-80°C for no reason and spikes up to 100°C (and after that CPU is being throttled to 600MHz or the PC shuts down).

I've checked pumps, it works. Also radiator is barely warm (something like 40°C, maybe even colder).

Screenshot of Psensor from a moment ago:

[image]

Throttling:

[image]

Random high temperature:

[image]

My PC:

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 2600
- cooling: SilentiumPC Navis 240 Pro
- mobo: MSI B350 Gaming Plus
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce Gigabyte RTX 2070 SUPER
- RAM: 4x8GB HyperX 16GB 3000MHz CL15 Predator Black
- PSU: SilentiumPC Supremo FM2 650W
- OS: Windows 10 & Pop!_OS 20.04

On Windows I'm using *AMD Ryzen Balanced* power plan.

I've changed thermal paste ~6 months ago (Thermal Grizzly Kryonaut). I didn't overclock any components. Also I've upgraded my BIOS and nothing has changed.

Comment: I would suggest contacting AMD directly. If you are confident that your cooling solution is adequate, then it's possibly a faulty CPU: even if it is a faulty sensor, they might possibly replace the entire CPU if it's under warranty. It could also be your water cooler, so if you are able to access even a cheap, stock air cooler and see if you see the same results, you can effectively confirm it is your CPU.

Comment: I don't really think that cooler is the problem. Becasuse temperature changes instantly. Is this even physically possible for CPU to heat from 40°C to 55°C in 1 second and then cool back to 40°C in 20-30 seconds?

Comment: That's normal. If you saw spikes up to 65 or higher, then I'd get a bit concerned.

Comment: @VanKosiara On just about anything those spikes do happen. I doubt the CPU is running temperature checks every cycle. Components can get very hot very fast, but the fact that the temperature is going well over 100 under what I assume is a low load, it could very well be the cooler.

Comment: Apparently I don't have stock cooler, I had to lost it somewhere when I was moving out. Is there something that I can check now or I have to buy another cooling solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got some time to buy and check a new cooler. I bought simple SilentiumPC Spartan 4. And of course it resolved the problem. There are still some spikes but much lower than before. Also idle temperature is now about 28-35°C and stress tempereature (gaming) is around 50-55°C. 
I wonder what happend to watercooling. Anyways I'm going to return it. Thanks for help!